# HTML table exported to excel opens as empty on Chrome

Tags: php, excel, google-chrome

I have a php script which generates an html table and exports to excel. This script is used in several places in my company's internal software. I just started getting reports that it isn't working and found that when used in Chrome -- and only Chrome -- it produces an empty file. Does anyone know what could be causing it? Did Chrome start ignoring the Excel header, and if so, is there a different header to use?

I am using the following headers:
`header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=${_POST['filename']}.xls;");`

Comment: So how are you exporting the html table to Excel? What library are you using? or are you simply trying to send html markup with an excel content type header?

Comment: I'm sending markup with an excel header.

Comment: Then what headers are you sending?

Comment: Edited that into the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: `${_POST['filename']}` doesn't look right at all: and I'd generally expect to see the filename quoted: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_POST['filename'] . '.xls;');` and you might want to vet the value of `$_POST['filename']`

Comment: Thank, but I tried that already, both with $_POST['filename'] and with a hardcoded filename. Both work in firefox and ie but fail in chrome.

Comment: Debug the headers actually being received by the browser using Chrome's developer tools

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with using a .csv, this works in Chrome and will open in excel:

```
header('Cache-control: private');
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $_POST['filename'] . ".csv");
```